# Can I speed this $.post callback somehow?

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook-graph-api

I'm using a `$.post` callback in the following to redirect the page after the data has been posted. Sometimes the page redirects pretty fast, but other times it can take a good 3-5 seconds.

I'm a novice, so not sure why it's taking so long. Is it waiting for the php to end? Anything here I can change to speed this up?

On another note... `encodeURIComponent` doesn't seem to be working. The URL always has a space in it like `?fbname=John Doe" which I am trying to remove with`encodeURIComponent`

Thanks!

```
FB.api('/me', function(response) {
                 $.post("addtodb.php", 
                 {fbname:response.name},
                    function(data) {
                    window.location.href = "step2.php?fbname="+encodeURIComponent(response.name); //redirect after post callback
                 })
            });
```

Comment: It's possible that encodeURIComponent is encoding the space and you're not seeing it being encoded because the browser is hiding this %20 or + and displaying it as a space

Answer (score 2):

If you use're using a tool like Firebug or Google Chromes inbuilt tools you can view network activity. This will give you an idea of where the holdup is. The wait time could be due to the responsiveness of the server, or even something within your JavaScript.

**Example:**
I can see that on my personal website Facebook's like.php had a fairly slow transfer time..
https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYYsD.png

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I checked it out in Chrome and Firebug, and you're right... it does look like the facebook oauth activity is at times slow. In some instances it's very fast, others its pretty slow. Guess there's not much I can do about that. Maybe I can have a lightbox display or something while waiting?

Comment: Solved this with the following ajax loading script...

    `jQuery.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function() {
     $('#loader').show()
    },
    complete: function(){
     $('#loader').hide()
    },
    success: function() {
     $('#loader').hide()
    }
    });`